# Bootstrap 3: Two collapsable navabrs with fixed-top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code, which seems to work if I keep both navbars static:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="./static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="./static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body >
    <div class="bothnavbars">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top nav1" role="navigation">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header ">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></span> Name</a>
            </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Sub menu link1</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- ./container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top nav2" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Name</a>
        </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Sub menu link1</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- ./container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="blockcontent">
Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css that I have added in main.css is:

```
.nav1 {
    margin-bottom:10;
}

.nav2 {
    top:0;
}

.blockcontent{
padding-top: 180px;
}
```

Now, if I want to make both navbars fixed to the top, I change

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top nav1" role="navigation">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top nav1" role="navigation">
```

Same for nav2. And I change the nav2 class to something like

```
.nav2 {
    top:60;
}
```

Now the page looks ok, but when I shrink my browser size and click on the buttons to see the menus, the first navbars doesn't function properly. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is `navbar-fixed-top` declares both `left` and `right` position to 0, so in fact the second nav is overlapping the first one since it takes the whole width of the screen.

To solve it, add this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bothnavbars">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top nav1">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top nav2">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="blockcontent">
Content
    </div>
```

**and CSS:**

```
.nav1 {
    position:fixed; top:60; width:50%; left:0; right:50% !important
}
.nav2 {
    position:fixed; top:60; right:0; width:50%; left:50% !important
}
```

I have changed your HTML code because it has errors as well, so I have included some easy to see HTML so you can see how it works and replace as needed, you can see a [Bootply sample here](http://www.bootply.com/m8DDEce3Gt)

For nav stacking one over the other, change the given CSS to this:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.nav1 {
    position:fixed; top:0; 
}
.nav2 {
    position:fixed; top:50px; background:#fc0 
}
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav1, .nav2{position:relative; top:0}
.nav2{top:-20px;}
}
```

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/va9FE6EfcQ) (note: the background color was added for visualization purposes, but is not needed, of course)

Comment: The CSS can be reduced to `.nav1 { right:50% !important } .nav2 { left:50% !important }`

Comment: This seems to give me one navbar with a right and left section. What I was looking for was a top navbar with another navbar underneath that one, both of which remain fixed when scrolling.

Comment: @Devin: thanks! It looks like it's working with your last addition. I also modified your example to include a toggle button, it's up at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/z5NviThzSc). The last thing I'm struggling with is how to make the height of the topmost navbar smaller. Every css change I make to `height` or `min-height` seems to break something else. Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Whoops. Wrong link. Here's the right [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uDu8VWBkup) link.

Comment: in that case you apply the height to the a element, like this: ` .nav1 .navbar-nav > li a{display:block; height:150px; background:#f00; }` and you add the same height value to the top position of the second nav, like this: `.nav2 {
    position:fixed; top:150px; background:#fc0
}` . Of course, if this is only for the second nav, you only modify the anchor element. You can see it in action at http://www.bootply.com/jQbNCGYpAp

Comment: I tried to make your example work for a smaller nav1, rather than a bigger one. I had to add `.nav1 .navbar-brand {padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; min-height:20px; height:20px; font-size:10px;}` to adjust the brand size. See it [here](http://www.bootply.com/mgXnoO4lFb). Does this make sense? Is there a way to make the toggle button smaller when collapsed? And can you explain what your `.nav2{top:-20px;}` does inside the `@media`? I can't understand why it's necessary.